# How would you use scanf() to scan for the value that you created before?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to create a program in C which asks the user to choose one of the options 
from the menu. So I've set float 1=7.20, 2=5.30, 3=4.80, 4=6.50, 5=10.80

I created a little menu with the options using these values and I asked the user to enter
either option 1 2 3 4 or 5.
How do I scan for user's input in this case?

Sorry, I'm just beginning my story with C.

Comment: You are using 5 floats? Why not use an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
  int choice;
  float value;

  scanf("%d", &choice);

  if(choice == 1)
      value = 7.2;
  etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using 5 floats.

1. Instead use a single float array.
2. Ask the user to input an integer.
3. Use that integer an input to display the option.

> ```
> float f[]={7.20, 5.30, 4.80, 6.50, 10.80};
> int i; 
>
> scanf("%d", &i); // between 1 to 5
>
> chosenVal=f[i-1];
>  .....
> ```

You may want to check whether `i` is within the range and `scanf` was successful.